# What is the difference between WebDriver.SwitchTo().Window() and WebDriver.SwitchTo().Frame()

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

A few days ago, I had the requirement to make my **WebDriver**(Chromedriver in that case) switch between 2 tabs on my browser (One of which has been automatically opened by clicking a link).

I was able to implement a solution using the following lines (**C#**)

```
var tabs = new List<String>(Driver.WindowHandles);
//Switches to the first tab
Driver.SwitchTo().Window(tabs[0]);
```

However, I recently came across some implementations that use frames and alerts, which confused me.

The [documentation](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/switch-commands/) has not been very helpful to me as I still have trouble figuring out use cases for each.

Could you please enlighten me what the difference between **Frame** and **Window** is for that purpose ( performance, reliability, cross-platform,... )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Frame :**

is a tag in **HTML**. However The  tag is not supported in HTML5.

The <**frame**> tag defines one particular window (**frame**) within a `<frameset>`

Normally, You must have seen **Iframe** in **DOM**. It's basically section of a HTML page.

Moreover, If you want to interact any element which is inside a frame , You will have to switch to frame.

**How** :

`SwitchTo().Frame(int frameIndex)` : using index

`SwitchTo().Frame(IWebElement frameElement)`   :  Select a frame using its previously located OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement.

`SwitchTo().Frame(string frameName)` :  Select a frame by its name.

**Windows :**

When you click on any any link and a new tab opens or a new windows itself open that's a window in Selenium.

**How** : You have already mentioned that in your Post.

Hope this'll be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In Selenium, Window can be different Tab in same browser instance or different browser instance. The context of `switch to window` is multiple pages or browser instance.

Frame inside web page, so the context of `switch to frame` is one Page, not multiple pages or browser instances.

Answer (score 0):

### Window Object

The [**Window Object**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp) represents an open window in a browser.

If a document contain frames ( tags), the browser creates one *Window Object* for the **HTML document** and one additional window object for each of the frame it contains.

As per the [**`WebDriver W3C Editor's Draft`**](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/) *WebDriver* commands happen in the context of either the [current browsing context](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-current-browsing-context) or the [current top-level browsing context](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-current-top-level-browsing-context).

### Driver.SwitchTo().Window(windowHandle)

The current *top-level browsing context* is represented in the protocol by its associated **window handle**. A top-level browsing context can be selected using the [**`Switch To Window`**](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-switch-to-window) command as follows :

```
Driver.SwitchTo().Window(windowHandle)
```

### Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frameReference)

Similarly, a specific *browsing context* can be selected using the [**`Switch to Frame`**](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-switch-to-frame) command.

```
Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[contains(@src,'<src_attribute_value>')]")));
```