# How to select a window through Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, window-handles

I  am looking to write a simple selenium test that will find a window with a title or URL and then select it, then select swap tabs once. I have tried using various things like

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle);
```

I have managed to write this function in Powershell, but because I cannot identify the Chrome window with Powershell I read that Selenium was the best way to go. I am using Visual Studio and have installed all the Chrome Drivers and everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**, you can't locate a *window* with a specific `title` or `URL` and then use it to **switch tabs**.

---

### Driver.SwitchTo().Window(windowHandle)

The current *top-level browsing context* is represented in the protocol by its associated **window handle**. A top-level browsing context can be selected using the [**`Switch To Window`**](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#dfn-switch-to-window) command as follows :

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(windowHandle);
```

You can find a detailed discussion in [What is the difference between WebDriver.SwitchTo().Window() and WebDriver.SwitchTo().Frame()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50393149/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-switchto-window-and-webdriver-switc/50396213#50396213)